# Regex to return all words in a line that starts with specific word

Tags: regex, perl

I know this may be a common question and a duplicate, but I don't know how to
express it well. For example, using Perl,

```
@arr = "a bb ccc" =~ /\b(\w+)\b/g;
```

can successfully get the three words.

But if I add one condition, that the line must start with a specific word, such as
**begin**(excluding in the result array)

```
@arr = "begin:a bb ccc" =~ /begin:.*\b(\w+)\b/g;
```

This time the array contains only the last match **ccc**

How should I write a correct regex?

Comment: think you may do like `if /^begin/ {/(\w+)/}`

Comment: I think you'll need to use an anchor and a multiline modifier. I haven't done much with perl though, maybe take a look at this if you haven't seen it, http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html#ANCHORS.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, you mean separating the Regex into 2 statements? but I now want to learn the Regex, in fact no real world question is at hand...

Comment: @AvinashRaj, /(\w+)/ will include every word, including begin, how to exclude it?

Comment: try `(?<!^)\b(\w+)\b`

Comment: @AvinashRaj, this answer seems to work, but still have to use TWO Regex?

Comment: If you want to do it with one regex try this `@arr="begin:a bb ccc"=~/(?:^\w+:.*?)?\b(\w+)\b/g`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: If you have an answer then you should post it as a solution, although the contents of your comment aren't valid Perl

Comment: @Borodin I don't know Perl well. But anyone should understand what I'm trying to say from the above code.

Comment: op uses regex tag. So he wants to do something with regex.  That's why I suggested above. If my concept is wrong then why people put three upvotes for that?

Comment: @LeiYang Leaving [idea](https://eval.in/471516) using [\G](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#What-good-is-\G-in-a-regular-expression%3f) as a comment. It's generally practicable to match an "anchored" sequence from what you need each match and is of good performance.

Comment: @AruneshSingh *condition, that the line must start with a specific word, such as begin...* Your "condition" is optional. This will match any `\b(\w+)\b` even without starting anchor.

Comment: @bobblebubble I thought he wants to match  both  `begin:a bb ccc` and `a bb ccc`  thats why he told *but still have to use TWO Regex* , But I was not sure enough that's why I kept it as comment.

Comment: @AruneshSingh I confused your name with Raj, I firstly agreed with your answer, but later found it did not exclude 'begin'. I updated the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you're looking for [contiguous matching](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html).

- [What good is \G in a regular expression?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#What-good-is-%5CG-in-a-regular-expression%3F)
- [perlre Assertions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Assertions)

> The \G assertion can be used to chain global matches

```
@arr = ("begin: a bb ccc" =~ /(?:^begin:|\G)\h*(\w+)\b/g);
```

See [demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/471516)

- `(?:^begin:|\G(?!^))` This part is to bind the matches to `begin:` at `^` [start](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).
   `\G` matches at the end of a previous match. Without `(?!^)` `\G` would also match at start.
- `\h*(\w+)\b` matches `*` any amount of `\h` horizontal whitespace followed by group `(\w+)` to capture one or more word characters if followed by a `\b` word boundary to `$1`.
- Instead of `\h+` use `[^\w\n]+` to match any characters that are not word-characters or newline in between. To match `begin:` anywhere in the string, remove the `^` start anchor.

Also [see demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bR9aH8/2)

`\G` is especially useful to match an "anchored" sequence and extract each subsequent match.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say very much about your data, especially what happens if there is no `begin` at the start of the line. But you probably want `split` instead of a regex pattern

Something like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $s = 'begin:a bb ccc';

my @arr;

if ( $s =~ /\Abegin:(.*)/ ) {
    @arr = split ' ', $1;
}
else {
    say 'No "begin"';
}

say join ',', @arr;
```

#### output

```
a,bb,ccc
```

Comment: Thanks, from the code I can see you're very well at Perl, and I'm newbie. May be this is example of more than one way to do it!

Comment: @LeiYang: What I was trying to say in the comments is that you shouldn't try to put a lot of work into a single regex pattern. The most import thing is that your code isa *clear*. For instance, if you want to check that a string begins with `A` and ends with `Z` you might want to write `/^A/ and /Z$/` instead of `/^A.*Z$/`. That's a poor example, as the single regex is pretty clear, but you can easily write something unreadable that is far simpler if you use two regexes, or even `split` or `index` etc.